# Order of composite index

Tags: mysql, optimization, index-tuning

Suppose I have a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
    JOIN table_b USING (id)
WHERE table_b.column = 1
```

I have an index on `id` and an index on `column` but often I add a composite index with both that can improve efficiency of queries like this.  My question is concerning the order of the columns in the index.  By trial and error I've found that sometimes the DBMS prefers the joined index first and sometimes it prefers the `WHERE` index first.

**In the above query is there a hard, fast rule I can abide by to know which key order will work best?**

Typically I just add both indexes, run `EXPLAIN` on the query and check to see which is preferred, then remove the other one.  But this process feels like it could be improved by a better understanding of the logic involved in determining index order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is to make the leading column in a compound index as selective as possible.  A good way to imagine this is with the phone-book analogy:  Imagine you need to find someone in the phone book, and there are two indexes... the first is Lastname, Firstname.  The second is FirstName, LastName.  Which index would you use to find someone named John Xylophone?  Surely you'd use the LastName, Firstname index since there are very few Xylophone entries, and it will take a lot less time than looking through all the John entries for one with the last name of Xylophone.

So, if `id` is highly selective, and `column` has low selectivity, you'd want the index to be `(id, column)`, however if `column` has high selectivity, and `id` has low selectivity, you'd probably benefit from having the index defined as `(column, id)`.

You might see an index on `(column, id)` being used if you are joining two tables on `id` with `where column = x` when `x` results in a substantially reduced number of rows needing to be joined.

Comment: @MaxVernon - You are half wrong.  When _both_ parts are tested with '=', selectivity is irrelevant.  Even your example is flawed.  A BTree index is drilled down via _all_ the keys simultaneously, not in two steps.

Comment: @Rick - this was an attempt to simplify the problem domain into lay terminology that is simple to understand and remember.  I've been wrong before.  I'm reading your excellent article now.

Comment: @RickJames Selectivity is the most obvious criteria. The other one is the type of the indexed field. Strings mangled with charsets and collations can be significantly slower than ints due to the more complex comparation. Especially combined with %LIKE%. Another factor is the length of tables combined with type of relation. When tables related as 1:1 are joined the longer one should be joined to the shorter `FROM few JOIN lot ON..` but it depends.

Comment: @Kondybas - Sorry, but I think that most of what you say is either misleading or wrong.  Selectivity is irrelevant in composite indexes.  Collations (etc) are slightly slower; fetching the rows is the big cost.  `%like%` is bad mostly because of the leading wildcard.  Table length is only slightly difference: example--The depth of a trillion-row index is only twice that of a million-row index.

Comment: [Cardinality & Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/should-i-put-the-higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-ra) -- 
[Cardinality and Composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315496/which-column-to-put-first-in-index-higher-or-lower-cardinality) -- 
[Single-column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113181/does-it-make-sense-to-use-an-index-that-will-have-a-low-cardinality)

Comment: I disagree with the rule of thumb: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/most-selective-first

Answer (score 5):

**For *this* query**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
    JOIN table_b USING (id)
WHERE table_b.column = 1
```

**The optimal way is execute it is**

1. The `WHERE` clause provides some filtering, so let's make use of it.  That is, have an index on `table_b` *starting with* `column`.  (Later we'll discuss whether to make it composite.)  So, the Optimizer will use that index to find row(s) of `table_b`.
2. For each of those rows, `JOIN` to `table_a`.  (Note that `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN` is being used; `LEFT JOIN` is a different story.)
3. To reach into `table_a`, an index starting with `id` is needed.  (Note:  `USING(id)` means `table_a.id = table_b.id`.)

So far, we have

```
b:  INDEX(column)
a:  INDEX(id)   -- though it probably exists as PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

**Covering?**

We don't know what other columns there are in the two tables.  If there are very few columns, then it might be tempting to build a "covering" index.  This is an index that contains *all* the columns needed *anywhere* in the `SELECT`.  The benefit is some performance speedup by looking only in the index's BTree and not having to touch the data BTree.

For `table_b`, it would be tempting to say `INDEX(column, id)`.  That would be good (and 'covering') if there were only those two columns.  But there are probably more columns.  So, probably `INDEX(column)` is all that is worth doing.

For `table_a`, I assume that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` (which is, by definition, unique and an index).  So nothing more is needed there.

**Bottom line**:  Use the two single-column indexes listed above.

*And this example does not exemplify anything about "composite" indexes.*  For more on that, see

[Cardinality & Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/should-i-put-the-higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-ra)
[Cardinality and Composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315496/which-column-to-put-first-in-index-higher-or-lower-cardinality)
[Single-column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113181/does-it-make-sense-to-use-an-index-that-will-have-a-low-cardinality)
[Indexing cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

> but often I add a composite index with both that can improve efficiency of queries like this...

**Better Example**

As I said, your example does not exemplify the question.  So, I'll try to answer "When should I use a composite index"?  There are many cases (see the links); I'll give you a simple case.

```
WHERE x = 1
  AND y > 2
```

The relevant characteristics are:

- `x` and `y` are in the same table.  (Can't build an index across two tables.)
- `AND` is used.  (`OR` can't be optimized.)
- One of the tests is with `=`.  (Composite won't help if both are ranges.)
- `y` is a "range" (examples:  `y>2`, `y LIKE 'm%'`, `y BETWEEN ... AND ...`).

**The general rule is**:

1. Put all the `=` columns first (`x` in my example)
2. Put *one* range column last (`y`)

That is, you must order it `INDEX(x,y)`.

For `WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2` (both `=`), it does *not* matter whether you have `INDEX(x,y)` or `INDEX(y,x)` .

**Another tidbit**:  With `ENGINE=InnoDB`, the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) are implicitly tacked onto each secondary key.  Hence, your `INDEX(column)` is the same as `INDEX(column, id)`.  But this fact does not play a role in this discussion.

**I realize that I am disagreeing** with other Answers here (and elsewhere), but I stand my ground.

Answer (score 2):

> In the above query is there a hard, fast rule I can abide by to know which key order will work best?

In the example you have given, your best bet is not to have a composite index at all if you are free to change the join order:

> ```
> create table table_a(id integer, dummy_a integer);
> create index index_a on table_a(id);
> create table table_b(id integer, col integer, dummy_b integer);
> create index index_b on table_b(col);
> ```

> ```
> explain select * from table_b join table_a using(id) where table_b.col=1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                    | rows | filtered | Extra      
> -: | :---------- | :------ | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :------ | :------ | :------------------------------------- | ---: | -------: | :----------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | table_b | null       | ref  | index_b       | index_b | 5       | const                                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where
>  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | null       | ref  | index_a       | index_a | 5       | fiddle_YRFDITQONPXNRMDBQSYV.table_b.id |    1 |   100.00 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d7c4f5b22b5c254ba7bbccdb4e1287c)*

Comment: But you _do_ have a composite index -- The PK `id` is implicitly tacked onto `index_b`.  And using `table_b` and `index_b` is _the_ optimal way to start this query execution.

Comment: You need more columns to avoid confusion with "covering", and to help differentiate whether "composite" is beneficial.

Comment: Hi Rick, can you prove this statement "The PK id is implicitly tacked onto index_b" with a dbfiddle? I don't think there is a PK on either table I created. I've made an edit regarding your point about extra columns to avoid confusion with covering, thanks.

Comment: It's been irritating that there is little 'proof'.  Run `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`, then observe the `key_parts`.  However, the 'hidden' PK when you don't have a PK does not show up even there.